# What does it mean for a shared object to be listed twice, both as found and not found, after setting LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld-preload, ldd

I am compiling a C++ executable (let's say `myexec`) and two of the libraries it depends on (let's say `mylib1.so` and `mylib2.so`), using GCC 8.5.0, on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.

Running `ldd myexec` returns:

```bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcf9852000)                                       
        libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007fa8571aa000)   
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa856f8a000)             
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa856d86000)                       
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fa856b82000)                   
        mylib1.so => not found  # First missing lib 
        mylib2.so => not found  # Second missing lib
        # ...more libs follow
```

Which means, AFAIU, that the two custom linked libraries are not found. I'd say this is expected, since the libraries are in a directory which is not searched by `ldd`.

I would expect that, setting `LD_PRELOAD` would help, so I run:

```bash
export LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/mylib1.so:/path/to/mylib2.so"
ldd myexec
```

which returns me:

```bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fc5a293c000)                                       
        /path/to/mylib1.so (0x00007fc5a31ed000)  # First lib found
        /path/to/mylib2.so (0x00007fc5a2e7e000)  # Second lib found
        libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007fc5a293c000)   
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc5a271c000)             
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc5a2518000)                       
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fc5a2314000)                   
        mylib1.so => not found   # First lib...also NOT found?
        # ...more libs follow
```

Note that `mylib2.so` is found, but `mylib1.so` is listed twice, both as found *and* not found.

So, my question is: how come `mylib1.so` is missing, if `ldd` lists it? Does it have to do with symbols not being found in the one I'm trying to link with `LD_PRELOAD`?

---

**Edit:** Even more cryptic for me is that soft-linking the `mylib1.so` library in `/usr/lib64`  leads to:

```bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3c3e7000)                                       
        /path/to/mylib1.so (0x00007f5dc2cfa000)  # First lib found
        /path/to/mylib2.so (0x00007f5dc298b000)  # Second lib found
        libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007f5dc2449000)   
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5dc2229000)             
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5dc2025000)                       
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f5dc1e21000)                    
        # ...more libs follow
```

i.e. The `mylib1.so => not found` entry is gone. However, I don't want to solve the issue like that, as it would mean messing with all other users of the machine.

---

**Edit 2:** <strike>I tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to something like `/dir/containing/mylib1/` but it does not work, still not finding the `mylib1.so`.</strike> In the end `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` worked, and it seems like one viable solution, but I would still like to know why `LD_PRELOAD` was not honored.

---

**Edit 3:** Running `LD_DEBUG=all ldd myexec` lists some extra info which I still don't understand:

```bash
     57257:     file=/path/to/mylib1.so [0];  needed by /path/to/myexec [0]
     57257:     file=/path/to/mylib1 [0];  generating link map
     57257:       dynamic: 0x00007f7d44ecdd40  base: 0x00007f7d44cbd000   size: 0x00000000002114c0
     57257:         entry: 0x00007f7d44cc2eb0  phdr: 0x00007f7d44cbd040  phnum:                  9

     # ... more lines follow
     
     57257:     file=mylib1.so [0];  needed by /path/to/myexec [0]
     57257:     find library=mylib1.so [0]; searching
     57257:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache

     # ... searches all remaining paths, like /usr/lib64, where I decided to make a soft link>
```

So it finds the `mylib1.so` I specify with `LD_PRELOAD`, but it's not satisfied, and keeps on searching for it.